# Empirical formula of coverage probability

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

Can someone explain me how this formula calculates the coverage probability.

Suppose I have a time series of size $n$. Then I can fit a model to this series and get its one-step ahead forecast and calculate its prediction interval (confidence interval) with lower bound as $L$ and upper bound as $U$. I have extra 10 observations that I am not using for modelling. So I can check whether these 10 observations lie within this interval or not. If it lies I am assigning one and if not zero.

I saw in a article that they are calculating the coverage probability as,

$ 1- \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{10} I_{i}}{10}$

where $I$ is the indicator variable.

Why they are deducting that probability by 1?

Do you have any idea about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First: Prediction interval $\neq$ confidence interval. With forecasting, you are generally intersted in prediction intervals. The formula you cite only makes sense if the indicator variable is 1 if the observation is *outside* of the prediction interval, and 0 otherwise.